# Was slaughtering cows in Kamchatka prohibited in the 1820s?

Tags: russia, law, animals, kamchatka

In *To the Pacific and Arctic with Beechey: The Journal of Lieutenant George Peard of HMS Blossom, 1825–1828*, Peard claims that in Petropavlovsk, Kamchatka, "nearly every family possesses a Cow (against killing which there is a positive order from the Government)".

Which authority made such an "order"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apparently the rule did exist. John Dundas Cochrane clarified its origin in his *[Narrative of a pedestrian journey through Russia and Siberian Tartary, from the frontiers of China to the Frozen sea and Kamtchatka; performed during the years 1820, 1821, 1822, and 1823](https://archive.org/details/narrativeofpedes00coch/page/n443)*:

> Much benefit has been derived to the colony from the exertions of the present Chief, Captain Rikord. The rule of never allowing a cow to be killed until she is past calving, is in itself excellent, but the stock on hand is so small that a century would elapse before what can be termed herds of cattle could be seen wandering and feasting upon the almost unhounded pastures of the Peninsula.